# How to increase resolution of a qgraph in png and export?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to save a `qgraph` in png format, but it is a very low-quality image.

I do not wish to save it as pdf

These is the code I used to create a social network `qgraph`.

```
mat1 <- read.csv("LR.csv ",row.names=1)
View(mat1)
qgraph(mat1 , borders = FALSE,edge.labels=TRUE,edge.color="black")
```

Comment: How are you currently saving your plot? If you're saving from the menu/by right clicking then the behaviour differs between R and Rstudio, and there are several ways of doing it in Rstudio, so you'll need to be clearer about what you're doing. 
If you're using `png()`, it has arguments `width`, `height` and `res` which can be combined to alter the image quality.

Comment: Thanks, @Miff for your suggestions. I am saving the graph using the png option but the default resolution is low. I tried changing the height, width but ended up with images that were too small or too big. When I had previously used ggplot, I could easily use ggsave for exporting good quality images without having to manually make changes. I was wondering if the qgraph package had an option like this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.